# GO gorilla/mux some pages serving html files return 404

Tags: go

I am working on this API in GO and im using gorilla/mux for my routing. THe home page with path "/" works fine, while routes like "/login" and "/register" return 404

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "go-api/controller/ad"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "path"
)

func homePage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    p := path.Dir("./public/views/index.html")
    w.Header().Set("Content-type", "text/html")
    http.ServeFile(w, r, p)
}

func showLogin(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    p := path.Dir("./public/views/login.html")
    w.Header().Set("Content-type", "text/html")
    http.ServeFile(w, r, p)
}

func showRegister(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    p := path.Dir("./public/views/register.html")
    w.Header().Set("Content-type", "text/html")
    http.ServeFile(w, r, p)
}

func main() {
    baseUrl := "localhost:9010"

    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/", homePage).Methods("GET")

    r.HandleFunc("/ads", Ad.GetAds).Methods("GET")

    r.HandleFunc("/login", showLogin).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/register", showRegister).Methods("GET")

    http.Handle("/", r)
    fmt.Printf("Server running at: %s", baseUrl)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(baseUrl, nil))
}
```

Yes, all 3 files exist in folder public/views:

- index.html
- login.html
- register.html

What am I doing wrong? -How do I fix it so that the pages will show normally?

Answer (score 0):

The cause is in the places where a directory is determined instead of the actual files to be used, e.g.

```
    p := path.Dir("./public/views/login.html")
```

Go's [documentation of Dir](https://pkg.go.dev/path#Dir) states:

> Dir returns all but the last element of path, typically the path's directory.

But since you want to deliver the actual file, you should use the file path. The handler function would then look something like this:

```
func showLogin(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    p := "./public/views/login.html"
    w.Header().Set("Content-type", "text/html")
    http.ServeFile(w, r, p)
}
```

Note the removed `path.Dir`.

`http://localhost:9010/login` now serves the `login.html` file as expected.
(Generally, for testing, it is always good to clear the browsing data before testing so that no cached data is displayed.)

Comment: In the mean time I found out that the routes work fine in a incognito mode, but not in my regular browser, even after clearing browser data (strange)

Comment: Hm, if I copy/paste your code and then remove `path.Dir` as described, your code works fine, even without incognito mode - maybe you made some additional changes in the meantime?

Comment: I made a small test project with your code slightly adapted: https://www.software7.biz/iertzzlmckljkjnrrst/gorilla.zip ("go-api/controller/ad" removed, the html only containing title and `path.Dir` removed). To start just type `go run .`.  Then call `http://localhost:9010/login` in a browser (use `http:` and not `https:`). Works ;-)